# Proving $(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) = (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C) \implies B = C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Indirect proof. Assume that $B \neq C$. Therefore I assume without loss of generality  that $\exists x (x \in B \land x \notin C)$. This leaves us with two possible cases:

$x \in A$. But then $x \notin (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$ and $x \in (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)$ which contradicts the given equality.

$x \notin A$. But then $x \in (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$ and $x \notin (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)$ which contradicts the given equality as well.

Therefore $B = C$.

Is this proof complete and correct?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: You only assume that `B` has any elements at all.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn In the case where $B\supsetneq C$ there surely will be some elements in $B$.

Comment: Some additional information: LHS is called symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$ denoted by $A\Delta B$. Given $A\Delta B=A\Delta C $ we get $ A\Delta (A\Delta B)=A\Delta (A\Delta C) $ and the two side of the s equation are precisely $B$ and $C$!